# How to concatenate HREF to get id from database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

NodeJS, Mongoose

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++){ %>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <a href="/article/<%=articles._id%>">
        <%= articles[i].title %>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% } %>
<% include partials/html-footer %>
```

How do I make it go to /articles/articles._id? I've tried -

```
<a href="/article/"+<%=articles._id%>>
```

as well. If there's anything else you need to see, let me know. Don't know what else to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the array index:

```
<a href="/article/<%= articles[i]._id %>">
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out a few hours after I posted it.